# How to use draggable with Bottom Modal Screen?

Tags: flutter, draggable

I have a **showModalBottomScreen** activated displaying several images in GridView.
[Here's my App Screen with BottomModalSheet on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZJ6V.jpg)

All of those images are **Draggable**
[Here's the Draggable Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meo4z.jpg)

`return Container(child: LongPressDraggable(data: img,feedback: img,child: img));`

What I need my app to do is : When I start to drag one of the images, the Bottom Modal Sheet should close(pop) and I must be able to submit the draggable onto a drag target. But the Bottom Modal Sheet closes and I am unable to retain the draggable.

This is what I used:
`onDragStarted: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop()`

The error message is get in my debug console:  OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should create a `PersistentBottomSheetController controller` inside your widget, along with `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key` for your widget's scaffold ( used to control the showModalBottomSheet ) .

And change `onDragStarted:() => controller.close()`

If you could provide more details about your app, maybe I would be of more help.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I tried this and it didn't work. Found out that Modal? Persistent bottom sheets fade the background out of context, so I couldn't really jump my Draggable from foreground to the back. Ended up using a SlidingUpPanel instead.